# Round borders separated in sections around circular image

Tags: border, css, css-shapes

I am wondering how it is possible to create the following effect using only CSS:

Desired output :

[image]

Currently, all I can think of is adding a border around the image. But how can I cut them and make sections out of them around the image?

This is my current CSS:

```
.avatar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: solid 3px #65C178;
    border-width: 4px;
}
```

And HTML:

```
<div class="avatar"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/soffes/128.jpg" /></div>
```

**Preview: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vz964/)**

This only gives a border around the avatar image, not the green sections with white spacings.

Comment: Note that the prefixes for `border-radius` used in the original fiddle are mostly unnecessary. `-webkit-` is still supported but deprecated, `-moz-` has been removed from Firefox 13, which came out two years ago, and `-ms-` and `-o-` never existed to begin with. I strongly advise against using prefixes unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vz964/7/)

**Output :** [image: round borders with white spaces around circular image]

### Explanation

**Creating the borders**

1. Use borders with border-radius to create the borders. 
   [step 1](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vz964/4/)
2. Then transform rotate to make the left top border appear at the right place.
   [Step 2](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vz964/5/) (don't forget to "unrotate" the image by rotating it the other way so it stays vertical)

**The white spaces**

3. Use pseudo elements to create the white spacings at the bottom and the right of the image.
    [step 3](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vz964/7/)

Unless you have very special requirements for browser support, you can remove the vendor prefixes for the `border-radius` property. Check [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/border-radius) for more info.

*CSS :*

```
.avatar{
    border: solid 4px #54BE69;
    border-left-color:#D5EDDA;
    padding:2px;
    display:inline-block;  
    border-radius: 50%;
    position:relative;

    transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.avatar img{
    display:block;
    border-radius: 50%;

    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.avatar:before, .avatar:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:-1;

    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
}
.avatar:before{
    height:4px;
    top:50%;
    left:2px; right:-5px;
    margin-top:-2px;
}
.avatar:after{
    width:4px;
    left:50%;
    top:2px; bottom:-5px;
    margin-left:-2px;
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I [forked it](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/mpp2h/) so that there are four of the little dividers because I thought OP needed them. He doesn't, but I'm leaving this here anyway on the off chance it's useful.

Answer (score 5):

Here you have an example with sass.. (quickly Googled)

http://codepen.io/geedmo/pen/InFfd

**EDIT:** As requested in comments here's a little improvement with some quick tweaks to that codepen

[**SASS DEMO LINK**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaHnv)

[image]

*SASS:*

```
// Colors
$progressColor: #65C178
$pendingProgressColor: #D5EDDA
$backColor: #fff

/* -------------------------------------
 * Avatar img
 * ------------------------------------- */
.avatar img
  border-radius: 50%
  border: solid 3px #fff
  border-width: 3px
  margin-top: 4px
  margin-left: 4px

/* -------------------------------------
 * Progress Bar
 * ------------------------------------- */
.progress-radial
  float: left
  margin-right: 30px
  position: relative
  width: 142px
  height: 142px
  border-radius: 50%
  border: 2px solid $backColor // remove gradient color
  background-color: $progressColor // default 100%


/* -------------------------------------
 * Mixin for progress-% class
 * ------------------------------------- */

$step: 5 // step of % for created classes

$loops: round(100 / $step)
$increment: 360 / $loops
$half: round($loops / 2)
@for $i from 0 through $loops
  .progress-#{$i*$step}
    @if $i < $half
      $nextdeg: 90deg + ( $increment * $i )
      background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, $pendingProgressColor 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient($nextdeg, $progressColor 50%, $pendingProgressColor 50%, $pendingProgressColor)
    @else
      $nextdeg: -90deg + ( $increment * ( $i - $half ) )
      background-image: linear-gradient($nextdeg, $progressColor 50%, transparent 50%, transparent), linear-gradient(270deg, $progressColor 50%, $pendingProgressColor 50%, $pendingProgressColor)
```

For the separator of the progress sections another mixin could be included

Comment: Interesting. Although is it possible to get the spacing - like in the picture I posted?

Comment: @abhitalks This is a reference for orientation. You've got the credits on the right.

Comment: @SDude: Fair enough. It would better have been a comment in that case. An answer would warrant some explanation.

Comment: I agree with @abhitalks . You could improve on this answer by explaining the code in detail. I for one would be interested in that.

Comment: What's with the `-moz-`, `-ms-` and `-o-` prefixes on `border-radius`? `-moz-` has been deprecated for **years** and is not even supported anymore since Firefox 13, and `-ms-` and `-o-` have **never existed** for that property. For that matter, I doubt `-webkit-` is needed anymore either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, OP included it in the original question and I copy-pasted his code for a quick example... Removing it..

Comment: Ah, so they were in the original question - apparently it had just been edited out by the time I posted my comment.

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution: [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8YMA6/)

**CSS**

```
.avatar img {
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-width: 4px;
    padding: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #65C178 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%), linear-gradient(0deg, #65C178 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="avatar">
    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/soffes/128.jpg" />
</div>
```

Note: change the `deg` value in the second linear-gradient to change the percentage filled.

Comment: +1 This is an interesting take. But please add the relevant portion of code as part of the answer.

Comment: Agreed, however it still doesn't tackle the problem of the spacing between the borders.

Answer (score 2):

We cant get the exact like your image. But something we can get it. Add the following line of code in your css.

```
border-top-color:#ff00ff;
border-bottom-color:#0000ff;
border-left-color:#00ff00;
border-right-color:#000;
```

Updated jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/vz964/1/

Comment: This is really close. Would it be possible to add spacing between each "percentage"/new color?